# With IBM MQ, how can I get the exact time that a message arrived in the queue?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

On the receiver side, I need to know how long the message stayed in the queue before I got it for processing.

I'm using Java and JMS.

Answer (score 1):

Upon further searching, I found a post in this forum with a similar discussion:
http://www.mqseries.net/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=71092&sid=97f90533407247be7150d81d550538a1

It's a convoluted solution but it appears to be the only way to know when a certain incoming message was effectively received.

It involves setting up an exit program that process outgoing messages, and if it is a COA, save the current timestamp (with messageId/correlationId) somewhere for later processing.

But the big question is: why don't IBM implemented an "arrival timestamp" property in the first place? It looks a trivial thing to do...

Answer (score 0):

You can access `JMS_IBM_MQMD_PutDate` and `JMS_IBM_MQMD_PutTime` properties - see [WMQ documentation](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032350_.htm). Bear in mind though this is the time when the message was put on the origin queue - when the message travels across queue managers this timestamp doesn't change.

If you can't use these properties directly - either you can't trust them or/and you want to only track the local PUT timestamp - then you don't have too many choices. The simplest recourse in my opinion would be to have a simple intermediate program at the same node, getting the message off the queue and putting it on another queue you will be actually servicing. As long as you care only about the payload and not the message context this simple setup will do. If you do need to carry over some context such as original userid, then you will need to use SET_*_CONTEXT options (and proper authorizations.) If you do not like the idea of an intermediate program I guess your last resort would be a channel exit at the receiving side, but in most cases that's quite an overkill.

In a completely different vein - depending on your actual requirements you may find that instead of tracking the time spent on the queue by every single message you may instead use MQ performance events, specifically [queue service interval event](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q036340_.htm) to make sure you keep servicing your input queue quickly enough. You can take corrective actions if the service interval gets above your threshold.

Comment: In my case, that property can't be used because the sender clock is untrusted. And if the message gets stuck in xtmit queue for any reason, I should not compute that time.

Comment: There is similar functionality withing Monitoring, The metric `QTIME` which can display short term and long term average-on-queue in microseconds. It requires `MONQ` to be active.